# How to build python 3.10 statically on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, msvcrt, python-3.10

I am trying to build python 3.10 statically.

To be precise I would like to produce a single exe if this is possible, and an exe and a zip if it's not.

When you download the sources there is a PCBuild directory, which contains the build.bat file which does not looks like can accept configuation of any kind. Also there is a solution which you cannot open with free vscode, but i've found a msvs professional trial. I have switched /MD to /MT and added a define as was suggested in other stackoverflow answers - but it resulted in a lot of "symbol not found errors".

The best luck i had was the unofficial "python-cmake-build-system" in github repo. It builds a static exe and a directory of modules. However it has no support for python 3.10 (yet, i hope) and unlike build.bat it does not autobuild all the dependencies - which prevents it from loading modules from a zip archive.

So, is there an easier way to build python statically - while embedding the .py(c) modules into the binary if possible? Maybe there's an undocumented switch for build.bat? Or should I just download and build all the dependencies for cmake repo?

PS. I am interested in a static build not in the py2exe and installers that would unpack everything into temp folder and run a dynamic build.

Comment: small remark: VSCode is nothing more than an editor. "VS community" is a free, full-fledged IDE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.